# sscanf - How should I handle this?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to parse an ascii string using sscanf. The string looks like this:

"Param1","Param2","","Param4"

The problem is that there could be a Param3 but it is not guaranteed. I'm also not interested in Param3 but must make provision for it in case it is present.

I'm parsing the parameters in the following manner:

```
char ParamStr[] = "\"Param1\",\"Param2\",\"\",\"Param4\"";
char Param1[10];
char Param2[10];
char Param4[10];

sscanf(ParamStr, "\"%[^\"]\", \"%[^\"]\", \"%*[^\"]\", \"%[^\"]\"", Param1, Param2, Param4);
```

But when I parse Param3, I get incorrect results for Param4.

What is the correct way to handle a parameter like Param3 that is "dynamic"?

Comment: Probably not the ideal task for `sscanf()`.

Comment: Parsing between the comma's is a great idea and works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the return value from `scanf` and use 2 different format strings:

```
// Try to scan all 4....
int count = sscanf(ParamStr, "\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\"",
    Param1, Param2, Param3, Param4);
// Didn't get 4? Try for 3 using a different format string
if (4 != count) {
    count = sscanf(ParamStr, "\"%[^\"]\",\"%[^\"]\",\"\",\"%[^\"]\"", 
        Param1, Param2, Param4);
}
```

Comment: An alternative to difficult to read formats is to take advantage of _string literal_ concatenation.  `#define PFMT "\"%[^\"]\"` `sscanf(ParamStr, PFMT "," PFMT "," PFMT "," PFMT, ...`